# how to submit a highlighted or marked region to R in "iESS" mode (with showing commands in R session)?

Tags: r, emacs, ess

In "ESS (Emacs Speaks Statistics)" mode, we can submit the current line in buffer to R using "C-c C-j" and submit a highlighted or marked region in buffer to R using "C-c C-r" and we can see submitted line/region in R session. I noticed that in "iESS (inferior ESS)" mode, we can still submit the current line and marked region using "C-c C-j" and "C-c C-r", respectively, but we can't see submitted line/region in R session (results are shown in R session).

I found that in "iESS" mode, I can use "C-c C-n" to submit the current line with showing the line in R session (i.e., "C-c C-n" in "iESS" mode is equivalent to "C-c C-j" in "ESS" mode). I failed to find how to submit a highlighted or marked region to R in "iESS" mode with showing the region in R session. Anybody know an answer?? Thanks!